# Round a number to nearest thousand

Tags: javascript

I know it is possible to round a number with `Math.floor` or `Math.round` with `jquery` but i need to round a non decimal number.

```
var num = 89250;
var round = Math.round(num);
```

Obviously it's not working, googled but no success, is it possible?

for example i need to round the number below:

> 89250 => **89000**

i did a trick but don't want a dirty work and also decimal number.

```
var num = 89250;
var round = Math.round(+num.toLocaleString('en').replace(',', '.'));
var total = round.toFixed(3);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: *"with jquery"* - You're not using jQuery at all here, you're using JavaScript's built-in methods. Anyway, should a number like `89750` be rounded *up* to `90000`?

Comment: What if value is ___`89750`___ ?

Comment: i know, `jquery` or `javascript` it does not matter, just need a solution @nnnnnn

Comment: @Rayon data is static not dynamic, i can control it, for this number i want to get 90000.

Comment: If the data is static, then why not have a static rounded number?

Comment: You have not searched even once for an existing solution. Not even the tiniest attempt of finding an answer on your own. Shame.

Comment: it's complicated one reason, hard to explain here, anyway i got a solution. @trincot

Comment: @Tomalak shame on you ! i searched but couldn't find any solution "" please don't judging people without knowledge ""

Comment: There are questions that are an exact match of title to your own. Besides, how likely is it that you are the first person with a problem this simple after almost 10 years of Stack Overflow. Seriously, get a grip. I copied your question title into Google and closed your question with the first hit that came up. Don't tell me you searched. You didn't.

Comment: no need to explain here and none of your business. but one thing: i did not know should search " nearest to thousand" ! i searched "round". also english is not my native language. enough! @Tomalak

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First divide your number by 1000, then round, and multiply again:

```
var num = 89250;
var rounded = Math.round(num / 1000) * 1000;
```

If you want a different [tie-breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) -- rounding ties down instead of up -- then apply the negation operator to the number before and after the rounding. Compare the difference in the output:

```js
var num = 89500;
var rounded = -Math.round(-num / 1000) * 1000;
console.log('rounding tie down: ', rounded);  // 89000


var num = 89500;
var rounded = Math.round(num / 1000) * 1000;
console.log('rounding tie up: ', rounded);  // 90000
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but any solution for this? `var num = 89500;` it returns `90000` but should return `89000`

Comment: That is less common behaviour. What would be the first number after 89500 that would round to 90000? Anyway, I added a solution that changes the rounding only for ties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, +1;